# How to use OnUpgrade android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have an app that uses sqlite to store some data. I want to add some data to that but don't want to add columns to table or change the table structure at all or add tables to db, I want just add some records to one table.

Is this a point to use OnUpgrade method or it didn't need to use this method for this record adding?

Is this adding some records to table become changing schema?

Answer (score 0):

No, in any structured database adding records doesn't modify the db schema. You can add records like in a SQL databse, using INSERT statements. You can follow the [d.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) tutorial to storing data locally.

Comment: It's fine to develop an app from scratch, because we learn the basics first. But for easy development, if you're not interested in scaling in production, you can try an ORM. Here is ORMLite: http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml.